# Understanding permissions and security in ofbiz : Not able to access application

Tags: java, ofbiz

I have create a application called smartfarm in ofBiz

the ofbiz-component.xml looks like this

```
<webapp name="smartfarm"
        title="SMARTFARM"
        server="default-server"
        location="webapp/smartfarm"
        base-permission="OFBTOOLS,SMART"
        mount-point="/smartfarm" app-bar-display="true"/>
```

and i am not able to access the application till i give super permission to the user.

my seed data looks like this

```
<SecurityGroup groupId="SETUP" description="Access setup screens" />
    <SecurityGroup groupId="CROP" description="Access crop screens" />
    <SecurityGroup groupId="CONFIG" description="Access detailed config screens" />
    <SecurityGroup groupId="LOCATION" description="Access location screens" /> 

    <SecurityPermission description="Access setup screens" permissionId="SMART_SETUP"/>
    <SecurityPermission description="Access crop screens" permissionId="SMART_CROP"/>
    <SecurityPermission description="Access detailed config screens" permissionId="SMART_CONFIG"/>
    <SecurityPermission description="Access location screens" permissionId="SMART_LOCATION"/>

<SecurityGroupPermission groupId="SETUP" permissionId="SMART_SETUP"/>
    <SecurityGroupPermission groupId="CROP" permissionId="SMART_CROP"/>
    <SecurityGroupPermission groupId="CONFIG" permissionId="SMART_CONFIG"/>
    <SecurityGroupPermission groupId="LOCATION" permissionId="SMART_LOCATION"/>
```

what is that i have to do to access the application if user have any of the permissions above?

Answer (score 1):

Your user needs both the OFBTOOLS and the SMART permission. From the configuration it seems that the OFBTOOLS permission is missing.